# E11000 duplicate key error from pymongo bulk upsert operation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bulk

mongodb: 3.4.24
pymongo: 3.13.0
using pymongo bulk upsert to insert/update documents in access_link collection, and get the following error:

```
{'writeErrors': [

{'index': 0, 
 'code': 11000, 
 'errmsg': \"E11000 duplicate key error collection: nap_poc.accesslink index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('6442995bf9606c000d3ae2a9') }\", 
 'op': SON([('q', {'a_link_id': 'GLWBA1-EBA-A1_1/3/3', '_id': {'$in': [ObjectId('6442995bf9606c000d3ae2a9')]}}), 
            ('u', {'service_saps': [{'_id': '1/3/3:101', 'qos_policy_in': '825', 'qos_policy_out': '1', 'ip_filter_in': '9020', 'ip_filter_out': '', 'mac_filter_in': '', 'mac_filter_out': '', 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333108:st=act:', 'parameters': {'customer_id': '1714', 'customer_name': '1714', 'customer_description': 'Vodafone UK Mobile Services'}, 'service': {'_id': '2111000', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_OMCH_VRF1', 'type': 'vprn', 'number_of_saps': 1, 'service_category': '', 'parameters': {'admin_state': 'enabled', 'vrf_import': ['VF_RAN_OMCH_VRF_IMPORT'], 'vrf_export': ['VF_RAN_OMCH_VRF_EXPORT'], 'route_distinguisher': '4445:211537', 'autonomous_system': '4445', 'maximum_routes': '2000', 'maximum_routes_threshold': '80'}, 'description': 'VF_RAN_OMCH'}, 'related_service': {}, 'related_service_sap': {'_id': '', 'name': '', 'description': '', 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered'}, 'service_interface': {'name': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'type': 'vprn', 'vlan': '101', 'ip_v4_addresses': ['100.123.146.5/30'], 'ip_v6_addresses': [], 'static_routes': [], 'static_routes_ipv6': [], 'bgp_neighbors': [{'neighbor': '100.123.146.6', 'family': 'ipv4', 'description': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'prefix_limit_ipv4': '2000', 'prefix_limit_threshold_ipv4': '80', 'bfd_enabled': 'enabled', 'parameters': {'prefix_limit': {'ipv4': {'limit': '2000', 'threshold': '80', 'log_only': 'log-only'}}}, 'group': {'peer_AS_number': '65068', 'export_policy': ['VF_RAN_OMCH_BGP_EXPORT_TO_CSG'], 'auth_key': 'qJISkqx+/G6JseefC11oDLhtLveJDSR5A4Cfb59Cdw==', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_OMCH'}}], 'bgp_ipv6_neighbors': [], 'ospf_neighbors': [], 'parameters': {'bfd_ipv4': {'tx_interval': '150', 'receive': '150', 'multiplier': '3'}, 'unmatched_lines': '                icmp\
                    no mask-reply\
                    no redirects\
                exit'}, 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333108:st=act:', 'ip_mtu': '1992'}, 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered', 'mtu': '', 'name': '1/3/3:101'}, 
                                    {'_id': '1/3/3:201', 'qos_policy_in': '825', 'qos_policy_out': '1', 'ip_filter_in': '9020', 'ip_filter_out': '', 'mac_filter_in': '', 'mac_filter_out': '', 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333120:st=act:', 'parameters': {'customer_id': '1714', 'customer_name': '1714', 'customer_description': 'Vodafone UK Mobile Services'}, 'service': {'_id': '2121000', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_UNENCRYPT_VRF1', 'type': 'vprn', 'number_of_saps': 1, 'service_category': '', 'parameters': {'admin_state': 'enabled', 'vrf_import': ['VF_RAN_UNENCRYPT_VRF_IMPORT'], 'vrf_export': ['VF_RAN_UNENCRYPT_VRF_EXPORT'], 'route_distinguisher': '4445:212537', 'autonomous_system': '4445', 'maximum_routes': '2000', 'maximum_routes_threshold': '80'}, 'description': 'VF_RAN_UNENCRYPT'}, 'related_service': {}, 'related_service_sap': {'_id': '', 'name': '', 'description': '', 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered'}, 'service_interface': {'name': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'type': 'vprn', 'vlan': '201', 'ip_v4_addresses': ['100.124.146.5/30'], 'ip_v6_addresses': [], 'static_routes': [], 'static_routes_ipv6': [], 'bgp_neighbors': [{'neighbor': '100.124.146.6', 'family': 'ipv4', 'description': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'prefix_limit_ipv4': '2000', 'prefix_limit_threshold_ipv4': '80', 'policies_out': ['VF_RAN_UNENCRYPT_BGP_EXPORT_TO_VODAMS_007920_920_01'], 'bfd_enabled': 'enabled', 'parameters': {'prefix_limit': {'ipv4': {'limit': '2000', 'threshold': '80', 'log_only': 'log-only'}}}, 'group': {'peer_AS_number': '65068', 'auth_key': 'qJISkqx+/G6JseefC11oDJJlW3xS2emOa+8Xm/O2eg==', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_UNENCRYPT'}}], 'bgp_ipv6_neighbors': [], 'ospf_neighbors': [], 'parameters': {'bfd_ipv4': {'tx_interval': '150', 'receive': '150', 'multiplier': '3'}, 'unmatched_lines': '                icmp\
                    no mask-reply\
                    no redirects\
                exit'}, 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333120:st=act:', 'ip_mtu': '1992'}, 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered', 'mtu': '', 'name': '1/3/3:201'}, 
                                    {'_id': '1/3/3:501', 'qos_policy_in': '825', 'qos_policy_out': '1', 'ip_filter_in': '9020', 'ip_filter_out': '', 'mac_filter_in': '', 'mac_filter_out': '', 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333126:st=act:', 'parameters': {'customer_id': '1714', 'customer_name': '1714', 'customer_description': 'Vodafone UK Mobile Services'}, 'service': {'_id': '2131000', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_ENCRYPT_VRF1', 'type': 'vprn', 'number_of_saps': 1, 'service_category': '', 'parameters': {'admin_state': 'enabled', 'vrf_import': ['VF_RAN_ENCRYPT_VRF_IMPORT'], 'vrf_export': ['VF_RAN_ENCRYPT_VRF_EXPORT'], 'route_distinguisher': '4445:213537', 'autonomous_system': '4445', 'maximum_routes': '2000', 'maximum_routes_threshold': '80'}, 'description': 'VF_RAN_ENCRYPT'}, 'related_service': {}, 'related_service_sap': {'_id': '', 'name': '', 'description': '', 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered'}, 'service_interface': {'name': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'type': 'vprn', 'vlan': '501', 'ip_v4_addresses': ['100.125.146.5/30'], 'ip_v6_addresses': [], 'static_routes': [], 'static_routes_ipv6': [], 'bgp_neighbors': [{'neighbor': '100.125.146.6', 'family': 'ipv4', 'description': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'prefix_limit_ipv4': '2000', 'prefix_limit_threshold_ipv4': '80', 'bfd_enabled': 'enabled', 'parameters': {'prefix_limit': {'ipv4': {'limit': '2000', 'threshold': '80', 'log_only': 'log-only'}}}, 'group': {'peer_AS_number': '65068', 'export_policy': ['VF_RAN_ENCRYPT_BGP_EXPORT_TO_CSG'], 'auth_key': 'qJISkqx+/G6JseefC11oDIQDsIcx6guLewjBB/n6HA==', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_ENCRYPT'}}], 'bgp_ipv6_neighbors': [], 'ospf_neighbors': [], 'parameters': {'bfd_ipv4': {'tx_interval': '150', 'receive': '150', 'multiplier': '3'}, 'unmatched_lines': '                icmp\
                    no mask-reply\
                    no redirects\
                exit'}, 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333126:st=act:', 'ip_mtu': '1992'}, 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered', 'mtu': '', 'name': '1/3/3:501'}, 
                                    {'_id': '1/3/3:601', 'qos_policy_in': '825', 'qos_policy_out': '1', 'ip_filter_in': '9020', 'ip_filter_out': '', 'mac_filter_in': '', 'mac_filter_out': '', 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333136:st=act:', 'parameters': {'customer_id': '1714', 'customer_name': '1714', 'customer_description': 'Vodafone UK Mobile Services'}, 'service': {'_id': '2141000', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_TEF_VRF1', 'type': 'vprn', 'number_of_saps': 1, 'service_category': '', 'parameters': {'admin_state': 'enabled', 'vrf_import': ['VF_RAN_TEF_VRF_IMPORT'], 'vrf_export': ['VF_RAN_TEF_VRF_EXPORT'], 'route_distinguisher': '4445:214537', 'autonomous_system': '4445', 'maximum_routes': '2000', 'maximum_routes_threshold': '80'}, 'description': 'VF_RAN_TEF'}, 'related_service': {}, 'related_service_sap': {'_id': '', 'name': '', 'description': '', 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered'}, 'service_interface': {'name': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'type': 'vprn', 'vlan': '601', 'ip_v4_addresses': ['100.126.146.5/30'], 'ip_v6_addresses': [], 'static_routes': [], 'static_routes_ipv6': [], 'bgp_neighbors': [{'neighbor': '100.126.146.6', 'family': 'ipv4', 'description': 'VODAMS_007920_920_01', 'prefix_limit_ipv4': '2000', 'prefix_limit_threshold_ipv4': '80', 'bfd_enabled': 'enabled', 'parameters': {'prefix_limit': {'ipv4': {'limit': '2000', 'threshold': '80', 'log_only': 'log-only'}}}, 'group': {'peer_AS_number': '65068', 'export_policy': ['VF_RAN_TEF_BGP_EXPORT_TO_CSG'], 'auth_key': 'qJISkqx+/G6JseefC11oDHRAesB7207OQRLLcm8nNQ==', 'name': 'VF_RAN_SPK_TEF'}}], 'bgp_ipv6_neighbors': [], 'ospf_neighbors': [], 'parameters': {'bfd_ipv4': {'tx_interval': '150', 'receive': '150', 'multiplier': '3'}, 'unmatched_lines': '                icmp\
                    no mask-reply\
                    no redirects\
                exit'}, 'description': 'vf=4445:cn=VODAMS:tl=3C03333136:st=act:', 'ip_mtu': '1992'}, 'classification_tag': 'unclassified', 'status': 'Discovered', 'mtu': '', 'name': '1/3/3:601'}], 
                   'a_link_id': 'GLWBA1-EBA-A1_1/3/3', 
                   'a_link_name': 'GLWBA1-EBA-A1_1/3/3'}), 
            ('multi', False), 
            ('upsert', True)])}, 
...
],
'writeConcernErrors': [], 
'nInserted': 0, 
'nUpserted': 0, 
'nMatched': 0, 
'nModified': 0, 
'nRemoved': 0, 
'upserted': []}
```

There is no index or unique constrains on access_link_id attribute of the access_link documents. The access_link collection may have multiple documents with the same access_link_id. The upsert filter is constructed in such a way that it update existing document if the document matches the access_link_id and ObjectId; otherwise, inser the document with a new ObjectId.

From the returned error, the upsert is evaluated as an insert, and the ObjectId for the insert operation conflicts with an existing ObjectId. Why is this? How's the mongodb ObjectId generated?

How is the new ObjectId affected if the database is copied from another server via mongodump and mongorestore?

Comment: `"_id"` always has a unique index, i.e., all `"_id"` values **must** be unique in a collection.  Do you already have a document with `'_id': ObjectId('6442995bf9606c000d3ae2a9')` but **not** `'a_link_id': 'GLWBA1-EBA-A1_1/3/3'`?  The `upsert` operation may be trying to create a new document with the same `"_id"` value which is not allowed by the unique index.

Comment: That's what I thought. But the code does not generate and assign ID to document, it must be generated by either PyMongo or the mongodb itself. I read somewhere the first 4 bytes of the ObjectId represent time in seconds since the Unix Epoch, and the last 3 bytes for the counter start from a random value. How can a conflicting ObjectId be generated, even if the existing ObjectId is from a different server?

Comment: I believe `upsert`, after not matching the filter/query (`'q'`), the new document inserted is composed of the filter and the other `"$set"` operations, etc. `'_id': {'$in': [ObjectId('6442995bf9606c000d3ae2a9')]}` looks curious in the filter/query - is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks to @rickhg12hs hint, I ran a few tests. As long as the number of ObjectId is not 1 (ONE) in the filter (the ObjectId list can be empty, or have two or more items), the bulk upsert seems working as expected. The failure happens only when there's one and only one ObjectId (exactly ONE item in the list) in the filter.